# Existe algum comando para terminar o programa em Python?

Tags: python-3.x, funções

Por exemplo, eu estou escrevendo um código

```
def soma(): 

 n1=int(input('digite um numero'))
 n2=int(input('digite outro'))

 soma = n1+n2

 print('A soma de {} e {} é {}'.format(n1,n2,soma))

#começo do programa

p=input('Você deseja somar?')

if p=='sim':
  print(soma())

print('Deseja subtrair')

.....
```

Caso eu queira terminar meu código na função da soma, existe alguma maneira de não fazer o programa executar as outras linhas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse seu exemplo, ajudaria se você colocasse uma cláusula **else**? Algo assim:

```
p=input('Você deseja somar?')

if p=='sim':
  print(soma()) # Realiza somente a soma caso a condição seja verdadeira
else:
  print('Deseja subtrair') # Realiza somente esse trecho caso a condição seja falsa
```

Comment: Ah sim rs, vdd. Nem me liguei.
e nesse.

Answer (score 2):

Python tem de facto forma de terminar a execução do programa fazendo:

```
sys.exit(0)
```

Assumindo que previamente incluiu a biblioteca `sys`:

```
import sys
```

No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
import sys # importação aqui
def soma(): 

 n1=int(input('digite um numero'))
 n2=int(input('digite outro'))

 soma = n1+n2

 print('A soma de {} e {} é {}'.format(n1,n2,soma))
 system.exit(0) # terminar o programa aqui
```

Esta saida é feita à custa de uma exceção `System.Exit`, tal como pode ver [na documentação](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit), que permite ao programa executar ações de limpeza. O parametro `0` passado indica que o programa terminou com sucesso.

**Nota**:
Apesar de funcionar desta forma o melhor seria mesmo alterar o fluxo do programa, tal como a resposta do @escapistabr mostrou, pois fica mais de claro de perceber como o programa segue, e acaba sendo mais simples que esta.

Comment: Shoooow^^ *-* 0-o